# Product for automatic implementation of web service

Tags: web-services, postgresql, wsdl, mule, talend

So I'm currently researching for a tool that on the one side gets WSDL file and on the other side is DBMS ( Postgres ) and the tool has to provide a way to specify which argument of the web service call to which column and table matches. I think example will make it clearer : we have a method getPersonByEgn(egn) and we have a database with table Persons and a column egn in the table. The tool has to provide a way to the user to match the egn column with egn parameter, to retrieve the row from the DB and convert the row to the return type of the web service method ( the object Person described in the WSDL ).

I know that IBM has such tool, but it is too expensive. I will be great find a open-source solution, but commercial software is also ok.

I researched a little bit, but to be sure I that I have found the right tool I have to spend a lot of time testing and trying it so I figured that I could ask the people that already have such experience. So the tools that I have found are : Mule ESB ( commercial ), Talend ( currently trying to find my way in the Talend Studio ).

Is there any other such tools and are these two capable of what I'm looking for ?

Comment: I'm not overly sure on your example. Do you mean you want a web service where someone provides some value (egn?) and then is returned some data on the person that has that egn value in the database table?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I'm trying Talend ESB Open Studio, but I'm having trouble with filtering the rows from the DB.